# Titanium TableView in Android

Tags: android, cross-platform, titanium

Hi I am facing problem with TableView. I have a TableView and added 5 rows to the TableView. Each row is having 2 images.

```
 var tableRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    className : 'row',
    objName : 'row',
    height : 'auto',
    top : '10dip',
    bottom : '10dip',
    left : '20dip',
    right : '30dip',
    height : '80dip'
});
var backgroundView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage : '/images/list-bg.png',
    width : '90%',
    height : '75dip'
});
var full= Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/images/boxfull.png',
    right : 10,
    top : 35,
    width : 20,
    height : 20,
    visible : false,
    objName: 'checkImage'
});
backgroundView.add(checkImage);
var empty= Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/images/boxempty.png',
    visible : false,
    right : 10,
    top : 35,
    width : 20,
    height : 20,
    objName: 'uncheckImage'
});
backgroundView.add(uncheckImage);
var requestName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : '' + json.requestName,
    left : '60dip',
    top : '5dip',
    right : '10dip',
    textAlign : 'left',
    ellipsize : true,
    wordWrap : false,
    font : {
        fontSize : '12dip',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    color : '#285a8c',
    height : '30dip',

});
backgroundView.add(requestName );
tableRow.add(backgroundView);
section1.add(tableRow);
tableView.setData(data);
```

When user clicks on a button then one of those images should be displayed to user.

```
var sectionArray = tableView.getData();
var sectionsLength = tableView.getData().length;
for (var i = 0; i < sectionsLength ; i++) {
    Ti.API.info("get sections-->" + i);
    var rows = [];
    rows = sectionArray[i].getRows();
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length - 1; j++) {
        if (rows[j].requestId != undefined) {
            Ti.API.error(JSON.stringify(rows[j].children[0]));
            rows[j].children[0].children[1].visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then if the user clicks on the row then other image need to be displayed and Previous image should be invisible.

```
           if (e.row.children[0].children[1].visible == true) {// if emptyimage visible is true then change visibility to false
            e.row.children[0].children[1].visible = false;
            // change visibility of checked image to true
            e.row.children[0].children[0].visible = true;

        } else {
            //change checked image visibility to false
            e.row.children[0].children[0].visible = false;
            // change unchecked image visibility to true
            e.row.children[0].children[1].visible = true;
        }
```

Every thing is working fine, I am able to load Table. But when user clicks on button each row in table is not displaying boxempty.png image. When I rotate the screen orientation or when I scroll's the tableview then only I can able to see boxempty.png image. The same problem is repeating to display boxfull.png when user clicks on table row. This problem I am facing in Android.

Comment: Try to adjust the height of the image view for android, try incrementing the height. It might resolve your issue

Comment: I specified 32dip height for ImageView but no result.

Comment: Just try to change the dimension of the image views to 25px each for width and height. I had met with same issue when creating a multiple selector picker. I think you're also trying for the same. I had used the above dimension there. I don't know the exact reason for issue. I've used pixels in entire application.

Comment: How funny it is. I specified 25px it is working. What is the wrong with it. Is there any reason for this.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason for issue. And one more thing about your code, you not need to use that second image, you just need to change the image of the first imageView(in that particular condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change the dimension of the image views to 25px each for width and height. I had met with same issue when creating a multiple selector picker. I had used the above dimension there. I don't know the exact reason for issue. I've used pixels in entire application.

```
var empty= Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/images/boxempty.png',
    visible : false,
    right : 10,
    top : 35,
    width : 25,
    height : 25,
    objName: 'uncheckImage'
});
```